# APEX 5.1 - Navigation menu gets reset to the top-level menu

Tags: oracle, navigation, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

With Oracle Apex 5.1, I use the side navigation menu as the main menu.

I have 3 levels of navigation :

```
1st level
|
+- 2nd level
|
+---- 3rd level
```

When clicking on the 3rd level navigation menu, it renders the pages and also reset the navigation menu to the 1st level only (hiding sub-menus of 2nd and 3rd levels)

I want to keep the 3 levels of navigation collapsed when clicking on the 3rd level navigation menu.

Can anyone tell me what are the relevant settings to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at what John Snyders suggests, [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4112909); shortly, create a JavaScript *page load* dynamic action

```
$("#t_TreeNav").treeView("option", "autoCollapse", false).treeView("expandAll")
```

which

- turns off the auto collapse feature (this lets only one node be open per level at a time) and then
- expands all the nodes.

All credits go to John, I'm just a copy machine.